# Symfony2 - Gedmo - Leave slug untranslated

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, doctrine-orm, slug

I'm working on a multilingual symfony 2 eCommerce site that works with slugs for the URL.

Currently the behavior for both languages is that the products's slug (based on the product name) is also translated. So I have this kind of URL:

- English: example.com/en/products/english-product-name
- Chinese: example.com/zh/products/chinese-product-name

The slug is based on the name, and thus saved for each language in a translations table. What I want is to only use the English slug for both languages. In my entity file it looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @Gedmo\Sluggable(slugField="slug")
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @Gedmo\Slug
 * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

I'm using [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) for my slugs and translations.

I've thought about creating an additional field that's not translatable and base the slug on that (instead of the product name), but it doesnt seem like a good way.